# Is the C# compiler free?

Tags: c#

I'm joining the [Facebook Hacker's Cup](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-hacker-cup/hacker-cup-2013-faq/). The rules say you can use any language with a free compiler; is C#'s free? I think so, but want to make sure...

I use Visual Studio Ultimate  (licensed from my school which is not free) and I would like to avoid having to learn a new language 1 week before the competition...

Comment: The compiler is part of the .NET framework. Also, you can get VS Express for free.

Comment: Yes, it's free. But Visual Studio Ultimate is _not_. Not sure if that's an issue or not; Visual Studio Express _is_ free though.

Comment: If you're a student, you can likely get Visual Studio Ultimate free via [DreamSpark](http://dreamspark.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is free.  Most versions of the Visual Studio IDE are not free, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Visual Studio Express comes with compiler that is free. Mono is another C# compiler that is free.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The C# Compiler is part of  the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4. You can download it, for free, here:

[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Choosing an IDE is another story. If the rules allow you to use your copy of Visual Studio Ultimate, then awesome. If not, you'll have to find something else. One of the [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) versions might suit your needs.

If not, check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).